# Recommended Software for Invoicing, with Customer & Order Databases?

Tags: crm, invoicing, inventory, point-of-sale

I can't seem to find software that suits my business' needs. We make t-shirt quilts. Essentially, each order is a somewhat complex series of options with prices that change based on certain variables, with lots of different potential add-ons. I am looking for the following:

1. Each order needs to have a fairly customizable and detailed invoice with fields that are calculated based on various inputs.
2. I also need these invoices to be linked to a customer and order database.
3. The invoices need to be printable as a receipt.
4. The software should be accessible both as PoS in the front room as the customer is ordering, as well as at the computer system in the back of the
   building.

Microsoft Access can do all these things except point 4, unless it is run as a web app in which case it can't do 3. So far it is the closest I've found.

I am a bit baffled because I don't feel like this is THAT unusual of a request. Does anybody have any recommendations? I would really prefer not to learn to program. Thanks so much!

Comment: What operating system should it run on?

Comment: “ Each order needs to have a fairly customizable and detailed invoice with fields” – You should expound on this aspect, giving precise details.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of solutions that may work for you.

Simple accounting software like Quickbooks or Sage 50 may work.  There are add-on modules for the POS.
Alternatively you may consider a point-of-sale software like AmberPOS or AccuPOS.
Or you may even consider an ERP like SAP Business One.
I have also seen some ecommerce systems do the trick like Shopify or Bigcommerce.

I recommend that you make a detailed list of all of your requirements, research and create a list of software systems to evaluate (some of the ones listed here might be a start) and then schedule demos to evaluate which one fits best for your business.